# Modbus server node register mapping strategy

Tags: modbus

I have a small raspberry pi like gadget running Linux. I'm using [uModbus](https://github.com/AdvancedClimateSystems/umodbus/) to let it act as a Modbus Server so that it can provide data and control points to a larger PLC system.

My device is a gateway to a series of sub nodes. Let's pretend for example, they are micro weather data sensors. For each one, the device gathers pressure, humidity, temperature, and windspeed. The subnode count is variable but can be as many as 100. It is possible that at some point, there might be an additional value or two added to what the sensors can read.

To flatten these values into modbus registers, I can choose to order by subnode first or subnode second.

A subnode first scheme might look something like

```
baseAddress = 01000 + (subnodeIndex * 10)
```

And then the individual values per subnode are just offset from that.

The subnode second scheme would assign a baseAddress for each value type (e.g. temperature starts at 00100, humidity at 00300, etc).

Is there a strong reason to prefer one scheme over the other? Or is there a scheme I'm missing? It seems that there's value in banking values together to take advantage of single block reads, but at the same time, leaving space for future expansion encourages some form of padding between values.

Comment: I like the first scheme.   All the values for a subnode are grouped together and can be read with a single request.   It will also be possible to read up to 12 subnodes (if <= 10 registers each) in one request.

Comment: It is not wise to connect all the components to a single line, a collapsing device can interrupt all communication (this error falls on all major producers.). The network design is based on the device type. It is grouped according to competence and reflexes, which provides the most healthy/fast communication (the most stable cycle is the shortest). Using more than one device pool always makes your job easier.